# Can't make a request using an 'user_id' as parameter on a Flask ApiRest

Tags: python, api, flask, rest

I made this request getting all the data from all the users, and it's working just fine:

```
@app.route('/account/bank-statement', methods=['GET'])
def get_bank_statement():
    try:
        bank_statement = TransferModel.query.all()
        transfer_schema = TransferSchema(many=True)
        bank_statement = transfer_schema.dump(bank_statement)
        array = np.asarray(bank_statement)
        lst= array.tolist()
        return make_response(json.dumps(lst), 200)
    except ValidationError as error:
        return make_response(error.messages, 422)
```

But when I try to get the same data from a specific `user_id` it returns an empty json:

```
@app.route('/account/bank-statement/<user_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_bank_statement_id(user_id):
    try:
        bank_statement = TransferModel.query.get(user_id)
        transfer_schema = TransferSchema(many=True)
        bank_statement = transfer_schema.dump(bank_statement)
        array_result = np.asarray(bank_statement)
        lst = array_result.tolist()
        return make_response(json.dumps(lst), 200)
    except ValidationError as error:
        return make_response(error.messages, 422)
```

What i'm doing wrong?

this is the model for that:

```
class TransferModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'transfers'
    transfer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.String)
    friend_id = db.Column(db.String)
    value = db.Column(db.Integer)
    card_id = db.Column(db.String)
    date = db.Column(db.String(10))

    def __init__(self, user_id, friend_id, value, card_id, date):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.friend_id = friend_id
        self.value = value
        self.card_id = card_id
        self.date = date

    def __repr__(self, ):
        return '' % self.user_id

    def remodel(friend_data):
        friend_data['card_id'] = friend_data['billing_card']['card_id']
        friend_data['value'] = friend_data['total_to_transfer']
        friend_data['date'] = date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        del friend_data['billing_card']
        del friend_data['total_to_transfer']
        return friend_data

    def save_to_db(self, ):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

Comment: be **VERY** careful using `list` or `str` as a variable name -- using reserved keywords will cause a world of pain -- I'm not sure if that's your issue, but fix that first and let me know if you still have an issue. FWIW `lst` is the norm you'll see around -- python wil let you override the built in, if you try to do something like `list([1,2,3])` you'll get an error that the object isn't subscriptable

Comment: Thank you very much, doing that right away. still don't think that's gonna solve the problem tho

Comment: I spent an afternoon hunting down a `str` when I first got started

Comment: What datatype is `user_id` is it an int or a str? If it is an `int` I suspect that's your problem -- I believe url params are casted as strings so you'd have to convert it back into an int before the query

Comment: user_id is a STR:
user_id = db.Column(db.String)

Comment: first you could try without `try/except` to see if it gives error message in console/terminal. You may also use `print()` to see what you get in variables.

Comment: I missed that, oops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand properly, but shouldn't you access specific user_id rows using `filter_by`?

So instead of doing:

```
bank_statement = TransferModel.query.get(user_id)
```

you do:

```
bank_statement = TransferModel.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id).all()
```